# Allow access to index file in subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have the following code in my `.htaccess` file, which is working exactly how I want it to.

However, I want to be able to access `mywebsite.com/admin/index.php`. What should I add to allow access to the admin folder?

It is working on localhost but not online.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /?urlget=$1&$2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your admin folder directly, then add that test first:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /?urlget=$1&$2
```

In that case, if the request is for admin/index.php it will go there without checking the rest of the conditions.

Comment: It seems like permission is being denied by my web hosting (godaddy), because if I remove the .htaccess file all together and try to access subfolders /admin or /image or /css the Forbidden screen is shown.

Any idea how I change the settings on the web hosting?

Comment: @StephenCroft yes, don't use GoDaddy hosting. They have the most incompatible system I've seen from a hosting company. Their setup always causes issues with Apache and rewriting. I honestly would find a different host as their are plenty good VPS providers out there that are cheap.